# Aptana-Studio install-Update error : jira.bat does not exist

Tags: aptana

I wanted to update my Aptana-Studio 3 but always get the following error :

> An error occurred while installing the items
>   session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.swift.jira.cli 2.5.0.1335554239, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.ChmodAction).
>   The action chmod failed - file D:\Aptana\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.swift.jira.cli_2.5.0.1335554239\jira.bat does not exist.

I checked, and jira.bat isn't there. If I remember well, I did have the same problem when I installed Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.1.2.exe a couple of month's ago, but as it seemed to work I didn't matter about it.

However, I would like to have it solved.
What can I do ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Would you file a bug at jira.appcelerator.org about this? It seems something the Studio developers should address.